# Filtered API is deprecated in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using java API to achieve below input but FilterBuilders.filtered is deprecated in JAVA API / Elastic 1.4
[image: Deprecated warning showing up]

```
filtered: {
    filters: {
        term: {
            "id": 5
        }
    },
    filters{
        {
            term: {
                "city": "newyork"
            }
        }
    }
```

My goal is I want to achieve similar to WHERE condition in MySQL

```
WHERE id=1 and city="newyork"
```

In the output, I want hits list and don't want separate buckets. I am newbie to elasticsearch and API.

How do I achieve what filtered(deprecated) was doing previously?

Answer (score 2):

It is too late but may be it can help someone else. 
The `filtered` query is replaced by the `bool` query from Elasticsearch version 2.0. See [Elasticsearch reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/query-dsl-filtered-query.html)

In Java, you could have something like:-

```
FilterBuilders.boolFilter()
                .must(FilterBuilders.queryFilter(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()))
                .filter(FilterBuilders.boolFilter()
                        .must(FilterBuilders.termFilter("id", 5))
                        .must(FilterBuilders.termFilter("city", "newyourk"))
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

filter is supported by JAVA API in elastic 1.4 as well. [Please check JAVA API query DSL Document](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/query-dsl-filters.html)

**Query DSL**

```
{
 "query": {
     "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "and": {
               "filters": [
                  {
                      "term": {
                         "id": 5
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      "term": {
                         "city": "newyork"
                      }
                  }
               ]
            }
        }
     }
 }
}
```

**JAVA API**

```
FilterBuilders.andFilter(
    FilterBuilders.termFilter("id", 5),
    FilterBuilders.termFilter("city", "newyork")
    );
```

Comment: Yes, It is supported but it shows deprecated / to be deprecated warning for filtered. My goal is to build API. Input will be key value pairs, I will loop through jsonNode and add filters one by one. That's why I need "filtered" API. and its showing me warning deprecated

Comment: Can you add warning message in your question? In elasticsearch 1+ version top level filters are deprecated and renamed as post_filter . Breaking Changes: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/1-0-0-rc1/

Comment: Its common java deprecated message with strike out on "filtered" word, like we see for any java code. It asks me to add ignore warning flag. In above comment I edited what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Added a screenshot of warning.